# extract string from a json object

Tags: extjs, textfield, json

I have an attribute in the extjs code defined as :

```
datajson: { 
    'name' : 'Hello',
     ....
}
```

Now I need to set the value of a textfield to the name defined inside this attribute.

I have tried the following but its not working:

```
Ext.getCmp('name').setValue((this.datajson.xyz.name).toString());
```

The id of the textfield whose value I am trying to set is 'name'

Here is the full code structure.

```
    Ext.define('Test', {
        extend : 'Ext.Container',

        alias : 'widget.myapp',

        datajson:{
                'xyz' : {
                    ...
                    "name" : 'Hello',
                    ...
                }
             },


        initComponent : function() {

            this.appcombo = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
                            store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', { 
                                   fields: ['text'], 
                                   data: [ 
                                        {text: "a"}, 
                                        {text: "b"}, 
                                        {text: "c"}
                                    ] 
                                }),
                                listeners: {
                                    select: function(combo, record, index) {
                                        Ext.getCmp('name').setValue((this.datajson.xyz.name).toString());
                                    }
                                }
                            });

           ...
           ...

           //Here we have a textfield within a Panel whose id is 'name'
```

So basically I am loading the page and then selecting one value in combo box which serves as the event to load the values in the text-fields with the data which is in datajson.

**EDIT:** More information added.

Comment: Why do you reference datajson with this, is it in the scope? What exception are you getting? amd you don't need to use toString.

Comment: I am receiving datajson from a rest service and the data in this datajson is what I use to populate my text-fields. It is in scope and I ain't getting any exception. It's just that the text-field value isn't being changed, i.e., I can't 'Hello' in the text-field whose 'id' is 'name'. Without toString() I will be receiving a JSONObject right? I can't populate the text-field with an object, rather, I need a string isn't it?

Comment: Edited. Please check.

Comment: your **this** reference is incorrect. 'this' inside your select listener does not refer to your container.

Comment: define var me = this; at the first line inside your initComponent and use that me to getdatajson inside your select listener

Comment: and you definitely don't require toString, datajson.xyz.name will return a string

Comment: Thanks for helping @Seram. As per your advice I added var dataObj = this in the first and line and changed the Ext.getCmp line to 'Ext.getCmp('name').setValue(dataObj.xyz.name);' but its still not working

Comment: @Seram Thanx for your help. Actually your point was correct regarding my this reference. I added the line var dataObj = this.datajson and now its working.

Comment: check this fiddle - https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/md4

Comment: @aayush_v20 - Glad to help. I've suggested based on your current code. But I think you should read a little more of form binding and other details. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope within your select function no longer contains `datajson`. To continue to use `this.datajson` you can pass the required scope into the function using `bind`

```
Ext.application({
name: 'Fiddle',

datajson: {
    'name': 'Hello'
},

displayName: function (combo, record, index) {
    Ext.getCmp('name').setValue((this.datajson.name));
},

launch: function () {
    Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        title: 'Contact Info',
        width: 300,
        bodyPadding: 10,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        items: [{
            xtype: 'combo',
            store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                fields: ['text'],
                data: [{
                    text: "a"
                }, {
                    text: "b"
                }, {
                    text: "c"
                }]
            }),
            listeners: {
                select: this.displayName.bind(this)
            }
        }, {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            id: 'name',
            fieldLabel: 'Name'
        }]
    });

}
});
```